# Broadcast receiver being called fine, but not showing notification

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-notifications

I have implemented a broadcast receiver to ask the user to restart the app if it is killed. I have confirmed that the broadcast receiver is being called fine, and it runs the below line but for some reason, I am not getting any notification.
Here is the code,

```
class ForegroundLocationServicesRestarter : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (intent.action != ForegroundLocationService.ACTION_RESTART_LOCATION_UPDATES) {
                return
            }
        }

        val notificationChannelId = "restartDeliveryApp"
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(notificationChannelId, "location_notif_chan", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
            val manager = context.getSystemService(LifecycleService.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

        val fullScreenIntent = Intent(context, DeliveryManActivity::class.java)
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra("RESTART_TRIGGERED", true)

        val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0,
            fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notificationChannelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_truck_red)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.restarter_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.restarter_message))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
            .build()
    }
}
```

The notification channel is unique, the app has notification permission and also, full intent permission in the manifest. Any help is highly appreciated.

Plus there is already one service notification, does that impact this in any way?

Comment: You are building a notification, but you are not asking the system to display it.  You need something like `val notification = ...build()` and then `notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)`

Comment: yes, that was what was missing! thanks!
figured that out and used pushy to display the notification,
`Pushy.setNotificationChannel(builder, context)
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(7, builder.build()) // same notification id to override`

Answer (score 0):

was not pushing notifications into the system to display! Just need to do this!

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(notificationChannelId, "location_notif_chan", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX)
            val manager = context.getSystemService(LifecycleService.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }

        val dmIntent = Intent(context, DeliveryManActivity::class.java)
        dmIntent.putExtra("RESTART_TRIGGERED", true)

        val dmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, dmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        // Prepare a notification with vibration, sound and lights
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notificationChannelId)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_truck_red)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.restarter_title))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.restarter_message))
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000)
            .setVibrate(longArrayOf(0, 400, 250, 400))
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(dmPendingIntent)

        Pushy.setNotificationChannel(builder, context)
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(7, builder.build()) // same notification id to override
```